# Middleware for Flash / AS3

Tags: flash, middleware, fmod, wwise

Almost everything has fmod and Wwise, and many engines have their own (xact, scream, whatever it's called in the udk), but flash is downright awful with audio and it doesn't appear to be getting any better.

Right now, to tweak sounds in the games my brother and I are making, I either have to go in and change the code or, even worse, go back to the sequencer and change the WAV.

**Is there a better way?  Is there an existing audio solution that I can do all my editing outside the code without destructively editing the wav file?**

Comment: Would a flash mixer that can loop some files and trigger others regularly, and shows the volume levels for the code help? I'm not great at flash, but have been thinking of making something like that for this reason.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think Flash's an awful platform, perhaps for a sound guy, but not for a scripter/programmer. If you can script, then it has a very sufficient API for audio, but many things might have to be coded from scratch, unless someone has done it already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the framework is that it's partially abandoned at this time. Adobe moved a lot of the original team members on other ventures and the product changed to Animate CC, in order to help the transitions from old technologies to new ones (javascript, css, html5).

I also remember from my early years with the framework up until now, they never got a proper audio engine going on, and it was always a problem with people that wanted to have quality sound in their games.

Of course you can code the hell out of it and make your own, but in the modern competitive game development market it doesn't really akes any sense, unless you code for leisure. :-)

It seems that it's never going to be equally developed as contemporary game middleware like Unity or Unreal, or other similar software.

Have you tried to switch to alternatives like Cocos2D, Clickteam Fusion, Construct, Corona SDK, GameSalad, GoDot etc? I know that final bit of my answer doesn;t cover any of your question, but if you are thinking into pursuing a career in game development, maybe it's a good time to switch frameworks.

Comment: If you try to download Animate CC it calls itself the program "formerly known as Flash Professional." So I'm not sure if Flash really is dead or if it is just renamed because it's for HTML5.